# How to ask turtles with multi attributes in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

How can I ask turtles with more than attributes to do something? These multi attributes should be all considered at the same time. Specifically, what I want to do is:

turtles-own [A B C D]

ask turtles with [**A = 1** and **B = 1** and **C = 1**]
[set color red]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote should work perfectly. [`and`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#and) allows you to connect multiple conditions together.

Comment: Yes, it works. I incorrectly wrote as the following in my codes.  
ask turtles with ([A = 1] and [B = 1] and [C = 1]) [set color red]
Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! Just FYI, the parentheses around `[...]` are unnecessary.